# Convert HTML files designed for IE 7, 8 and 9 to PDF using Aspose PDF

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, aspose, aspose.pdf

I have several thousands of HTML files that are designed for and work only in IE 7, 8 and 9.

When I try to convert these to using c# with the code below, they are not properly converted. (i.e. they are converted similar to how it is displayed in IE 11 which is not what's needed).

Link to HTML file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8mzln3jjify4yi0/input.zip?dl=0

If you open the HTML file with the current version of IE and go to Developer Tools within IE and emulate IE 7, 8 or 9, the HTML page is displayed properly.

Code:

```
String basePath = "C:\\temp\\";
HtmlLoadOptions htmloptions = new HtmlLoadOptions(basePath);
// Load HTML file
Document doc = new Document("input.htm", htmloptions);
// Save HTML file
doc.Save("output.pdf");
```

How can I get the HTML files to be converted to PDF exactly like how they look in IE 7, 8 or 9? Are there any options or parameters that can be changed to make them convert properly as needed?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the scenario using latest release of [Aspose.Pdf for .NET 16.10.0](http://www.aspose.com/downloads/pdf/net/new-releases/aspose.pdf-for-.net-16.10.0/) and I am unable to notice any issue. As per my observations, the PDF file is properly being generated. Please take a look [resultant PDF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzdeg0gmwligcv1/_output.pdf?dl=0).

*PS, My name is Nayyer and I am developer evangelist at Aspose.*

Comment: Could you check this again? I have uploaded the correct files to the same link in the question. The previous files weren't actually the files that I was testing with. the HTML files should look like this on IE: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5tnwgpjcm6ixt3/sdfsdfsdf.png?dl=0  (note the section on the bottom)

Comment: Hi, I still see the same HTML file in link shared in your first post. Can you please re-share the link.

Comment: I have re-shared and the link is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8mzln3jjify4yi0/input.zip?dl=0 Please make sure to extract all the contents in the zip file so that the resource files are accessible and then open in IE and not any other browser

Comment: I tried the HTML to PDF conversion with latest release v17.2.0 and I can see that not all HTML content is rendered in PDF and its similar to viewing file in IE-11 with mode IE10 or Edge. But when viewing HTML in mode 7,8 or 9, the complete HTML content appears in browser.
 
Do you also face have similar observation or am I missing something. Please acknowledge, so I can reply accordingly.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Hence the question title: **Convert HTML files designed for IE 7, 8 and 9 to PDF using Aspose PDF**

Comment: I have logged above stated issue with an ID PDFNET-42389 in our issue tracking system. As soon as its resolved, we will intimate you.