# Convert HTML to PDF using HtmlRenderer

Tags: c#, .net, html-to-pdf, html-rendering, html-renderer

I am looking to use HtmlRenderer to convert an HTML file to a PDF file. I have seen it being mentioned on several sites that it is possible. However, I don't seem to be able to find any basic sample code to do this.

I have added the following NuGet package.

```
Install-Package HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp
```

That's about as far I have got. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429220? That question is for Aspose and this is for PDFSharp

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.  I looked at the PdfSharp documentation and couldn't see how to convert from Html.  Unfortunately, the quality of the PDF produced wasn't great.

Comment: To be very clear, this is a community library, not one directly associated with the developers who made PdfSharp. You won't find docs for it on the PdfSharp website.

Comment: How is this too broad? I have a HTML file. I want to convert it to a PDF file using PDFSharp. This is very specific.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
using TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator;

string html = File.ReadAllText("input.htm");
PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PageSize.Letter);
pdf.Save("document.pdf");
```

Comment: Doesn't work on headless mono servers due to lack of x11 server

Comment: To clarify, `PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf`

Comment: As per the question package "HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp" which depends on "PdfSharp" needs to be installed, the Htmlrenderer package does in fact have a pdf generator.

Comment: @slayernoah can you help me in css data property of this function

Comment: This package is not compatible with .net core.

Comment: I tried this on some fairly basic HTML that contained some tables and it created a PDF with errors in it, with most of the pages being blank.

Comment: @AliRasouli ‘Polybioz.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.Core’ is compatible with .net core. Have tested in 6.0.